# Changing text color of radio buttons on clear form in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, radio-button

I'm using C# for a Winforms app and I can't seem to be able to change back to the default/'not selected' color on my 3 groups of radio buttons. I know there's a way without having to do it by each button individually. The part in the `foreach` for clearing the checked state works fine. Here's what I have tried.

```
 public void ClearForm()
        {
            foreach (RadioButton radio1 in carbonationGroupBox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList())

                if (radio1.Checked == true)
                {
                    radio1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    radio1.Checked = false;
                }

            foreach (RadioButton radio2 in strengthGroupBox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList())

                if (radio2.Checked == true)
                {
                    radio2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    radio2.Checked = false;
                }

            foreach (RadioButton radio3 in sweetnessGroupBox.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().ToList())

                if (radio3.Checked == true)
                {
                    radio3.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    radio3.Checked = false;
                }
```

Here's the code for three radio buttons from a one of the groupboxes that changes the color to begin with.

```
private void topStrengthHydromel_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    topStrengthStandard.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    topStrengthSack.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    topStrengthHydromel.ForeColor = Color.Lime;
    strengthRadionButton = "Hydromel";
}

private void topStrengthStandard_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    topStrengthHydromel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    topStrengthSack.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    topStrengthStandard.ForeColor = Color.Lime;
    strengthRadionButton = "Standard";
}

private void topStrengthSack_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    topStrengthHydromel.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    topStrengthStandard.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    topStrengthSack.ForeColor = Color.Lime;
    strengthRadionButton = "Sack";
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do again ? How do you change their color to begin with ?whats the problem in this code ?

Comment: How about having one more `RadioButton`? say, having "nothing" as its text

Comment: @ Ian... There can't be another radio button for "nothing" as one radio button from each group must be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I discovered was in the order of events inside the `foreach` area.

This order:

```
            if (radio1.Checked == true)
            {
                radio1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                radio1.Checked = false;
            }
```

was triggering the _CheckChanged event and putting the color back to Lime.

```
private void topStrengthHydromel_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    topStrengthStandard.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    topStrengthSack.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    topStrengthHydromel.ForeColor = Color.Lime;
    strengthRadioButton = "Hydromel";
}
```

Switching the order so the `radio1.Checked = false` happened before the `radio1.ForeColor = Color.Black;` did the trick!